# Android PreferenceScreen (AppCompat v21) - touch color

Tags: android, android-preferences, styling, android-appcompat

[image: Preference screen]

I use **AppCompat v21** with custom material theme color (**green**), I have used some hacks to preserve correct colors on **lowest API** than Lollipop. But I cannot find, **how to change** on the **preference screen** the touch **pressed color** from blue to grey or to other color, as is shown in the screenshot?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you found solution yet?

Comment: Hello Michal, not yet :(